# Why isn't my byte array returning correctly from SQL?

Tags: java, arrays, sql-server, jdbc

I'm working on a small application that uses an SQL database to keep track of users, and as part of that, I wanted to store the hashed user password & salt hashes in the SQL database. Both my salt and hashed passwords are byte[] arrays.

For some reason, when creating a user the salt I get back from the server is just... not correct. I can't figure out why. Here are the two methods that I imagine are causing it.

This is where I save the salt. (You'll notice I also print it to check)

```
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
byte[] salt = new byte[16];
sr.nextBytes(salt);

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
md.update(salt);
byte[] hashedPass = md.digest(passwordInput.getText().getBytes());

System.out.println(salt);
PreparedStatement pstmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, salt) VALUES (0, ?, ?, ?)");
pstmt.setString(1, desiredUser);
pstmt.setBytes(2, hashedPass);
pstmt.setBytes(3, salt);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Then this is where I try to pull the salt and hashed password for authentication:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT username, password, salt FROM users WHERE username=?");
        pstmt.setString(1, username);
        ResultSet passSalt = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if (!passSalt.next())
        {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Unknown User");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("There are no users found with that username. Please consider using the register button if this is your first time, or contacting support if you are having trouble accessing your account.");
            alert.showAndWait();
            return;
        }

        byte[] salt = passSalt.getBytes("salt");
        System.out.println(passSalt.getString("username"));

        System.out.println("Salt: " + salt + "length: " + salt.length);

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        md.update(passSalt.getBytes("salt"));

        System.out.println(passSalt.getBytes("password"));
        System.out.println(md.digest(passwordInput.getText().getBytes()));

        if (passSalt.getBytes("password").equals(md.digest(passwordInput.getText().getBytes()))) {
            System.out.println("LOGGED IN!");
        }
```

They're stored as a varbinary on the SQL server, but from what I understand that just holds binary and getBytes should return the full array. I would really appreciate any help with this.

I've considered a few workarounds (Like converting it into a string, etc) but I'd really prefer to solve the problem instead of avoiding it.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: How can you tell it’s not correct?  `println(passSalt.getBytes("password"))` won’t print anything useful.  And arrays cannot be accurately compared with `equals`;  use [Arrays.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(byte%5B%5D,byte%5B%5D)) instead.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the `users` table definition?

Comment: Also: SHA1 hashes are 256 bits, i.e.: 32 bytes. You're throwing away half your salt hash by storing it in a `byte[16]`.

Comment: Apparently, this was caused by a rather silly issue. My passwords weren't validating correctly, since as @VGR pointed out, .equals() doesn't work on arrays. I troubleshot by printing the byte arrays (Which again, as VGR pointed out doesn't print anything useful) - However, I guess I wasn't thinking straight and thought that the print statements (Which I now realize are probably memory addresses for the array) were some kind of representation of the array.

Switching it to Arrays.equals() fixed all my problems.
This has been a wonderful first experience asking on here, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is is correct. However, it's worth pointing out that if you are implementing password validation, you shouldn't use Arrays.equals().  Instead, you should use a constant time comparison function that protects against timing attacks.

I lifted the following code from somewhere in the BouncyCastle sources, iirr, and has passed a couple different rounds of fuzz testing.

```
/**
 * Compare every byte so validation time is constant and, thus,
 * protect against timing attacks.
 */
public static boolean equalsHash( byte[] expected, byte[] presented )
{
    boolean all = false;
    if ( null != expected && null != presented && 
         expected.length == presented.length ) {
        all = true;
        for ( int ix = 0; ix < expected.length; ++ix ) {
            boolean same = expected[ix] == presented[ix];
            if ( !same ) {
                all = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return all;
}
```